# How to change brightness on puppy linux?

Tags: brightness, puppy-linux

I just installed puppy linux but the screen is literally burning my eyes. The <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Brightness</kbd> key on my laptp doesn't work. I tried to go to setup and change the gamma but it just make the colors darker, the screen itself keeps being extremly bright so I think it's due to the backlight.

How can I diminish the backlight or the thing that keeps the screen bright despite me lowering gamma ?

**Edit:** in fact when I'm in command prompt mode (GUI closed) the screen is still very bright. Is there a way to fix that too ?

**Edit:** I managed to add `acpi_backlight=vendor` in GRUB as you can find on the internet to fix this problem but this doesn't change anything. Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> still doesn't work and changing the brightness file in `acpi_video` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. See if /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/ exists. If it does

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```

gives the max allowed brightness, and you can set brightness thus (where X is a value 0-'max_brightness'):

```
echo X >/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, I change brightness to 2 (max brightness = 7), restart the GUI but it doesn't change anything

Comment: did the value you set definitely take? you could try this as alternative: `tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness <<< 2`. Have a look at more suggestions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight).

Comment: well when I restart GUI `actual_brightness` is set to 2

Comment: in fact it's not only the GUI but also the screen while in command prompt mode too.

Comment: oh dear. I think a solution, if there is one, will be quite hardware-specific, prob good idea to add details of your hardware (i.e. exact laptop model) in the question.

Comment: it's a lowcost and old samsung RV515

Comment: see a possible solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/348247/samsung-laptop-brightness-issue-can-t-change-brightness-on-my-laptop), unfortunately the OP never came back to say if it worked.

Comment: found that already, tried but doesn't work, when I add acpi_backlight=vendor in grub it deleter the acpid_video folder with brigthness inside but the key still doesn't work

Comment: I'm out of ideas, except to try a different distro. Lubuntu maybe?

Comment: Yeah probably what I'm gonna try ty

Answer (score 0):

Have just tried `echo X >/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` on my HP 6450b with Puppy 5.7.1 and it does the job fine.

Answer (score 0):

my speculation success, i use "echo 200 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness" where my max brightness on intel_backlight is 976. ACER 4741 Intel Display

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 300 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

works for IGPs (Integrated Graphic Processors), like Intel chips.

```
echo X >/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

probably for external graphics cards.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Menu > Desktop > Redshift

There is a Screen Brightness Setting.

Answer (score -1):

on slacko  or puppy linux use the tool gamma calibration tool in setup for screen -100 +100

setup/puppy setup / graphics screen open monitor gamma calibration

i had to do this when using a tv as a monitor to soften  the brightness

but now got it just  right , only probelm i had is the screen resolution with using a tv  had to settle for 1040